# Child DialogFragment is dismissed by parent DialogFragment dismiss()

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-navigation

Using Navigation Components, a `Fragment` opens a `DialogFragment`, which may open up a second `DialogFragment`. Dismissing the first `DialogFragment`, will dismiss the second as well. However, I like to let the second `DialogFragment` to stay active until is dismisses itself.

Probably this is as intended. In my case it's a fragment opening a custom Share Bottom Sheet dialog. The bottom sheet is dismissed after an item is tapped. When an item is clicked and the result is long lasting, a loading dialog is  shown. The loading dialog dismisses itself when it is done.

So, the hierarchy is: MainFragment - Share DialogFragment - Loading DialogFragment.

I've tried navigating to the loading dialog using a global action instead of a dialog to dialog action, but that did not have any influence.
Using (its' parent) `MainFragmentDiretions.action**` inside the Share bottom sheet resulted in a crash. Good, it should.

A solution would be:

1. Let `MainFragment` open the loading dialog. I'd prefer neither DialogFragments depending on its' parent.
2. Hide the Share bottom sheet at item click and dismiss when the loading dialog is dismissed. I also do not like this  dependency.
3. Having the lifecycle of the Loading Dialog not depend on the Share  bottom sheet.

How to prevent the loading dialog from being dismissed if the share dialog is dismissed, without shifting more responsibility to `MainFragment`?

Comment: Dialog creating another dialog is a bad design, you are fighting with code because of that, solve the design problem and you wont fight with the implementation

Comment: Is it really? Since it aren't actual `Dialog`s, it are `DialogFragment`s, which are `Fragment`s themed as a dialog.

Comment: A dialog is a component in design in general, if this were vanilla js we will be discussing the same but referencing the alert method, with any other framework we will be referencing modals, the name of the class is irrelevant, the component is the same. You are implementing a bad design, thar bad design is turning in a troublesome implementation, solve the design problem and the implementation will be easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're passing ChildFragmentManager of dialog fragment to your loading-DialogFragment,
You can prevent the loading dialog from being dismissed by using two ways:

1) By using android Dialog instead of DialogFragment.
2) By passing the ChildFragmentManager of MainFragment or FragmentManager of your activity, here's an example:

```
class MainFragment : Fragment() {

    fun displayDataDialog() {
        DataDialogFrag().show(childFragmentManager, DataDialogFrag.TAG)
    }
}

class DataDialogFrag : DialogFragment() {

    fun displayLoadingDialog() {
        val loading = LoadingDialog()
        if (parentFragment != null) {
            loading.show(parentFragment!!.childFragmentManager, LoadingDialog.TAG)
        } else {
            loading.show(fragmentManager, LoadingDialog.TAG)
        }
    }

    companion object {
        const val TAG = "data_dialog"
    }
}

class LoadingDialog : DialogFragment() {

    companion object {
        const val TAG = "loading_dialog"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input! I'm actually using the new Navigation Component. This handles showing the fragments and - more importantly - the back stack for me. Bypassing this by using the fragmentManager makes the app crash eventually. I'll try out using a dialog.